# trying to exclude elements from an IEnumerable structure using Except

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to remove elements from an IEnumerable type from another IEnumerable.

Here I get the complete list

```
var tiposObj = from t in context.sistema_DocType
                               select
                                   new tgpwebged.Models.SettingsModels.TipoIndiceModel
                                   {
                                       id = t.id,
                                       tipo = t.tipoName
                                   };

                classificacaoModel.tipos = tiposObj.ToList();
```

And here a partial list to be excluded from the first

```
  var tiposAtribuidosObj = from t in context.sistema_DocType
                                        join c in context.sistema_ClassificacaoTipo on t.id equals c.idTipo
                                        where c.idClassificacao == classificacaoId
                                        select new tgpwebged.Models.SettingsModels.TipoIndiceModel
                                        {
                                            id = t.id,
                                            tipo = t.tipoName
                                        };
                classificacaoModel.tiposAtribuidos = tiposAtribuidosObj.ToList();
```

Here is how I am excluding:

```
classificacaoModel.tiposNaoAtribuidos = classificacaoModel.tipos.Except(classificacaoModel.tiposAtribuidos);
```

No elements is excluded from the first list. Can´t figure out why. They have same structure and same types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET framework has no way to compare 2 instances of `TipoIndiceModel`.
For this you have to implement [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)  or derive from `EqualityComparer`.

Hint from MSDN on [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

> This interface supports only equality comparisons. Customization of
>   comparisons for sorting and ordering is provided by the IComparer
>   generic interface.
>
> We recommend that you derive from the EqualityComparer class
>   instead of implementing the IEqualityComparer interface, because
>   the EqualityComparer class tests for equality using the
>   IEquatable.Equals method instead of the Object.Equals method. This
>   is consistent with the Contains, IndexOf, LastIndexOf, and Remove
>   methods of the Dictionary class and other generic
>   collections.

Comment: Actually the article states doesn't fully describe process of comparison of two instances. I still don't get why both Equals() and GetHashObject() have to be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

They may be the same type, but they are not the same instance.

The solution is to override `Equals` on `TipoIndiceModel` to provide member equality rather than the default reference equality. Consider implementing `IEquatable<TipoIndiceModel>` too!

Reference:

IEquatable interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx

> If you implement IEquatable, you should also override the base class implementations of Object.Equals(Object) and GetHashCode so that their behavior is consistent with that of the IEquatable.Equals method.

Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx